# Get user input from command prompt in Java?

Tags: java, input

I am fairly new to programming and I am stuck with a problem.

I want to write a small calculator program that does nothing more than reading to numbers from the command prompt and adds them together.

My problem now is, how do I get the numbers typed by the users?

Thank you :)

Comment: Just a simple google search like 'Java get input' would solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

read documentation for java.util.Scanner